# Salt states using tags from salt-cloud in AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, salt-stack, salt-cloud

I have some salt states that are applied to some specific minions using the minion id.
Now I am moving to a cloud provider, and need to apply this states based on tags that salt-cloud can set.

IE. I have an instance runnning in AWS (not provision by salt-stack), I can saltify it with salt-cloud and saltify module, and now I can recognize my minion:

```
root@instance1:~# salt instance1 test.ping
instance1:
    True


root@instance:~# salt-cloud -f get_tags my-ec2-eu-west-private-ips resource_id=instance1_awsid
my-ips:
    ----------
    ec2:
        |_
          ----------
          key:
              TagName1
          resourceId:
              instance1_awsid
          resourceType:
              instance
          value:
              Value1
        |_
          ----------
          key:
              TagName1
          resourceId:
              instance1_awsid
          resourceType:
              instance
          value:
              Value2
```

I wish to apply my states based on this values:

IE: instead of the clasic:

```
salt instance1 state.highstate
```

or

```
salt instance1 state.sls configure.service
```

I wish to do something like:

```
salt TagName1=Value1 state.highstate
```

or

```
salt TagName1=Value1 state.sls configure.service
```

Comment: salt-cloud is still a hack for EC2 instance provisioning.

Comment: @mootmoot Is there a better way to provision the ec2 instances as minion than using salt-cloud ? Or a hack is the best option of salt?

Comment: For mean of continuous integration, maybe you should try terraform. In saltstack, to provision a salt-master and subsequent salt-minion is not straightforward.  i. salt-cloud can create the instance and identify it by the name it created. It cannot apply tag to it.   ii. You can only use salt.states.boto_ec2.instance_present to add/change the tag.  OTH, using terraform is cleaner, because you can tag the instance and also pass saltstack bootstrap string during provisioning.

Comment: salt cloud is _still_ a hack in 2020

Answer (score 1):

I will answer myself and maybe save some time to others.

Looks like you cannot use that tags to provide states, however, you can use some of the modules from salt-contrib, to add this tags to the grain items.

https://github.com/saltstack/salt-contrib/tree/master/grains